# Increase performance of PHP DOM-XML. Currently takes too long time

Tags: php, xml

I have an array which contains 7000+ value

```php
$arrayIds = [
    'A001',
    ...,
    'A7500'
];
```

This `foreach` loop gets node value inside a node in a given XML file

```php
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('myxml.xml');

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$data = [];

foreach ($arrayIds as $arrayId) {
    $expression = "//unit[@person-name=\"$arrayId\"]/@id";
    $col = $xp->query($expression);

    if ($col && $col->length) {
        foreach ($col as $node) {
            $data[] = $node->nodeValue;
        }
    }
}
```

It takes approximately 70 seconds. I can't wait any longer than 5 seconds

What is the fastest way to achieve this?

Segment of the XML file:

```
<unit person-name="A695" id="PTU-300" xml:space="preserve">
    <source xml:lang="en">Related tutorials</source>
    <seg-source><mrk mid="0" mtype="seg">Related tutorials</mrk></seg-source>
    <target xml:lang="id"><mrk mid="0" mtype="seg">Related tutorials</mrk></target>
</unit>
<unit person-name="A001" id="PTU-4" xml:space="preserve">
    <source xml:lang="en">Related tutorials</source>
    <seg-source><mrk mid="0" mtype="seg">Related tutorials</mrk></seg-source>
    <target xml:lang="id"><mrk mid="0" mtype="seg">Related tutorials</mrk></target>
</unit>
...
<unit>
...
</unit>
```

Anyway, I'm doing this on an M1 Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the way you use XPath to find an element. Each time you run it for each name, it will search the whole document, even if it's the first item.  This is because it could find multiple values and doesn't know to stop after finding the first.

Alternatively, this uses XPath to find all of the names and checks each one if it is in the list of names you are looking for.  If so, it extracts the id and adds it to the list.

It's difficult to test how long this will take, but it's easier for you to test than me...

```
$data = array_fill_keys($arrayIds, null);
$arrayIds = array_flip($arrayIds);
$expression = "//unit/@person-name";
$cols = $xp->query($expression);
foreach ($cols as $col) {
    if (isset($arrayIds[$col->nodeValue])) {
        $parent = $col->parentNode;
        $data[$col->nodeValue] =$parent->attributes->getNamedItem("id")->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

Using `array_flip()` makes the names to search for as the index, so `isset()` can be used rather than doing a search of the array.

I've added the name as the key to the output array, so you get something like...

```
Array
(
    [A001] => 4
)
```

Comment: But then you are searching the ID array each time. You can likely speed this up further by flipping `$arrayIds` to a dictionary and then doing an isset instead of the `array_search`. Also, moving to XMLReader will likely also increase speed to some extent.

Comment: Might also be worth trying the Union operator. So instead of doing one query for each ID (in the OPs original approach), concat the queries with `|` and then go through the resulting DOMNodeList.

Comment: Just tested it. Doesn't work as expected. It's just like checking the `$arrayId` in the array exists or not. It's not searching based on `$arrayId` xpath query. Thank you anyway

Comment: @mending3, so you are saying it doesn't find the matching values from `$arrayIds`?

Comment: yea. I've updated the XML's segment so you can get the better picture of it

Comment: instead of showing: `['PTU-4', 'PTU-300']` , it shows `['PTU-300', 'PTU-4']`

Comment: It's not adding `$data` on the first matching `$arrayId`.

Comment: Out of interest - how does it perform?

Comment: It's now performing in an instant. Don't need to wait anymore. Do you know how do I get the `<mrk>` value inside the `<unit>/<seg-source>` tag based on your code?

Comment: You can use `$xp->evaluate("string(parent::*/seg-source/mrk)", $col)`, using `$col` as the second parameter says start from here.  As this is an attribute it then uses the parent axis.

Comment: When there are multiple `<mrk>` inside the `<seg-source>`, it only gets the first value of `<mrk>` tag

Comment: It has to be an array when there are multiple `<mrk>`

Comment: never mind. seems I solved it myself. Thank you much once again